# Find all sticky bit files on my FreeBSD Server

Tags: unix, freebsd

I need to get a list of all files (no directories) on my FreeBSD Server that have the sticky bit set. I am fairly sure that this is done with find, but I can't get the correct format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an easy one:

```
find . -type f -perm -1000 -print
```

Comment: @Radix this will find all files but not check for the sticky bit

Comment: No problem Radix, I have also copied your other stmt as that would be my next question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
find . -type f -perm -1000 -print
```